# Direction of shear along an oblique plane under a compressive force

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics

I think this is a low hanging fruit mechanics question. Here is a picture depicting what I am interested in:

[image: Pic 1]

Say I have a compressive force (green arrow) acting perpendicular to the blue block's front surface. As the blue block's oblique surface comes into contact with the orange triangular block, a force will be imparted. Below I have depicted two possible force diagrams of the forces **applied by the blue block** (note that the normal force applied by the rear **rigid wall** has been omitted in these diagrams).

[image: Pic 2]

What I am uncertain of is the direction along which the shear arrow (**light blue arrow**) should be oriented. If anyone could offer some intuition as to why one direction is more logical than the other, I would appreciate it. My impression is that **Case 2** is the correct direction because if the rigid wall were lower (as depicted below), then the blue block would rise up and to the right. As it traverses this path, the blue block is scraping against the orange oblique surface in the direction of its motion.

[image: Pic 3]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I overlook the difficulty of your question, but you simply decompose the original force applied (green arrow) into a normal and tangential component. The sum of these components should therefore give you the original force. This doesn't work in your case 1. Case 2 is the correct decomposition.

Comment: I originally thought that, too. Assuming the vectors' values are positive, Case 2 is represented by:  $\vec{G}=\vec{B}+\vec{P}$ And Case 1 is represented by: $\vec{G}+\vec{B}=\vec{P}$, where $G,B,P$ stand for green, blue, purple, respectively. I then thought to myself, "What is (physically) stopping Case 1 from happening".

Comment: 1) At equilibrium, considering the blue block, the green force and the force exerted by the orange block on the blue block should balance, meaning that the sum of shear and compressive stress exerted by the orange block should yield the exact opposite of the green force 2) The stress exerted by the blue block on the orange block are exactly the opposite of those found in 1). This should leave no ambiguity!